# Two target labels and custom loss function in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, loss-function, multilabel-classification

Using python and any machine learning library, I'm trying to have two target labels and a custom loss function. From my understanding, there is only one way to achieve this and that is by using Keras. Is this correct?

Here is a list of other things I have tried, have I missed something?

**LightGBM**

[This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-loss-functions-for-gradient-boosting-f79c1b40466d) is the first that pops up when searching for custom loss functions. Unfortunately, LightGBM doees not support more than one target label and [it doesn't seem like that's going to change anytime soon](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/524).

**XGBoost**

Has the same problem as LightGBM, you cannot have multiple labels only multiple target classes (Done by duplicating those rows) as discussed [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/santander-product-recommendation/discussion/25506).

**SciKit-Learn: GridSearchCV and make_scorer**

This initially looked good as you can have several target labels. However, the make_scorer method only scores the result of the model and it is not the loss function the model itself uses.

Comment: Why exactly do You want to have two labels ?

Comment: The two target labels are dependant and I cannot create a correct loss function with two separate problems.